# unable to retain 4 nameservers in resolvconf

Tags: dns, resolv.conf, resolvconf

Here is my /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base file contents:

```
# leave commented out above line lin resolvconf...as its listed in another file.
options timeout:1 attempts:1
nameserver 10.0.4.15
nameserver 10.0.2.18
nameserver 10.0.10.32
nameserver 10.0.3.25
search xyzdomain.com
```

But for some reason only 3 nameserver values are ever retained in

/etc/resolv.conf

I run

resolvconf -u

to regenerate the file...what am I missing?

Comment: Most likely, it's being updated by the dhcp client. You can have a look at this article: "Linux Make Sure /etc/resolv.conf Never Get Updated By DHCP Client" by Vivek Gite

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/dhclient-etcresolvconf-hooks/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a limit set at compile time for the libc resolver. The `man resolv.conf` page says:

> "Up  to  MAXNS  (currently 3, see <resolv.h>) name servers may be
>   listed, one per keyword."

So without recompiling the resolver, you can't have more than three.

Comment: if I recompile the resolver I'm making my Ubuntu a custom kernel?

Comment: No, because the resolver is part of libc, but not of the kernel.